# add category to home screen

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am new to magento. I want to display 2-3 products to home screen.

I created new category to display it on home page. I added single product to that category.
And I added this code to cms/pages/home/content

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4"}}

         And

{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

But item is not displayed in home page. 
I don't know what the problem. Any Help would be appreciated. Let me know if you need to anything else.

I am getting this message "There are no products matching the selection". I added product in this category.

category

[image]

cms/home/content

[image]

Comment: Please check your category page, is product display in category page or not?

Comment: @AnkitaAgrawal you can see it in screenshot tht product is added to the category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you have written as static text means you have to write as

**first click on cms home page>content>SHOW/HIDE Editor**

then write your block code and save page

hope this help you

Comment: I added tht code in cms/page/home/content. I specified this in que. Let me knw if u can think of any other problem. Thanks for your response.

Comment: i told you that first click on show.hide editor then write your code'it's wysiwyg editor

Comment: ok. My mistake. I wrote this code after clicking on show/hide editor. Still not getting any product but getting message "There are no products matching the selection". It shows me one product in categories in backend.

Comment: then there are not assign any product to this category id=3,please double check this category and category is active or not,,please check

Comment: it's category id is 3 and it's active. i added screenshot in que.

Comment: because you have added root category,,you have to click-on first magento Default category then click on add sub category and make new category take this category id and assign some product this new category ,it works 100 %

Comment: thanks for your help but m still getting same message. added new screenshots.

Comment: please check all possibility like product is stock,product is enabled .category active ,

Comment: i checked these possibilities but could find the problem.

Comment: please clear all cache or re-index data,i think this is only possibility left for you...

Comment: i ran it successfully. i don't know wht's the prblm was. but it's working when i created product-category from scratch. at the begining I was writing this code in header and your ans helped me solve the problem.

Comment: it's my pleasure...enjoy

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. But be sure about this points:-

```
1) Category should be active
2) Products assigned to category should be visible & in stock
3) code should be placed in home page after clicking on show/hide Editor button
4) Clear cache
```

Comment: i checked with all these points but couldn't find the prblm. are there any other suggestions?

Comment: couldn't find the prblm . but when i created category/product from scratch. it's working now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine. Click on Show/Hide Editor button to Hide editor mode then copy and past `{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}`

Try this once, hope this will help.

Comment: i m getting this message "There are no products matching the selection".

Comment: @BSThakrar, as per your category page screen shot, Smart Phone category ID is : 4

Comment: first it was 3 but then i created new category so now its 4. and i also changed in code.